# Why is there no set with much RC Straight tracks?

Tags: trains, city

after visiting many Lego events (brickmania, antwerpen, BE), I wish to expand my train layout much more than adding a box or two of 7499 ...

Why does Lego didn't released a set with, for example 24 straight track ( #53401 )

Even if 7499 contains flex rails, I don't like these, they are noisy.

Any tips for finding some ??

I can't imagine peoples who exposes layout in 5 meters by 8 meters with 4 tracks have bought a pallet of 7499 !

Answer (score 3):

According to [Brickset](http://brickset.com/sets/containing-part-4279714) there are 8-8 straight track pieces in all of these sets (including the [sets](https://brickset.com/sets/containing-part-6070018) with straight tracks without metal conductors):

- [7896](http://brickset.com/sets/7896-1)
- [7499](http://brickset.com/sets/7499-1)
- [3677](https://brickset.com/sets/3677-1/Red-Cargo-Train)
- [7898](https://brickset.com/sets/7898-1/Cargo-Train-Deluxe)
- [7939](https://brickset.com/sets/7939-1/Cargo-Train)
- [60052](https://brickset.com/sets/60052-1/Cargo-Train)
- [60205](https://brickset.com/sets/60205-1/Tracks)
- [60337](https://brickset.com/sets/60337-1/Express-Passenger-Train)

The [60098: Heavy-Haul Train](https://brickset.com/sets/60098-1/Heavy-Haul-Train) has 12, and both of [60336: Freight Train](https://brickset.com/sets/60336-1/Freight-Train), [60198: Cargo Train](https://brickset.com/sets/60198-1/Cargo-Train) have 16 straight pieces.

This seems to be the maximum amount, even the large complete train sets do not contain more than 16 straight tracks.

You might have more luck purchasing them piece by piece from other AFOLs, or see if there is a Pick-a-brick shop in your area.